# iOS 9 UIImageView scaling is erratic

Tags: ios, ios9

I have a UICollectionView in my app. Each cell is about a third the width of the screen (in portrait orientation) and is square. Inside each cell is a UIImageView whose mode is set to "Scale To Fill" (in IB) and has constraints on each edge that force it to fill the cell.

On iOS 7 and 8, images would consistently perfectly fill each cell.

On iOS 9, scaling varies each time the view appears, and sometimes changes when the cell is clicked:

- images sometimes are small, and sit in the upper left hand corner
- images sometimes scale to fill as they should.
- images sometimes scale slightly larger than the cell, and change size when the cell is selected.
- images sometimes disappear completely when a cell is selected.

If it somehow matters, the image gets set in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method of the collection view like this:

```
cell.artImageView.image = artImage;
```

Where "artImage" is a UIImage. (Obj-C).

UIImageViews are pretty simple and straightforward. Did Apple "improve" them with some new property I need to set? Really stuck here.

**Update**: Tried to reproduce this in a new project and couldn't. Some kind of weird leftover IB juju. But totally replacing the collection view controller, cell and image view in IB did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was an extra view that wasn't "installed" for the size class.

I had this:

[image]

And changed it to this:

[image]

And now everything looks right!